# Windows Forms Log in and Dashboard

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to see and hear some reviews on my current WinForms Login and Dashboard code.
It's a desktop application to be used only internally and not over the web.

If you have any code suggestions - I'd be more than happy to see it and see where I can improve.

**LoginScreen.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Technical_Application.Classes;
using Technical_Application.Forms;

namespace Technical_Application
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.username != string.Empty)
            {
                usernameTextBox.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
            }
        }

        //Login Button
        private void loginBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MySQL connection to retrive user details into a class on succesfull log in
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //Get count, username, id, and their access id
                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select count(*), username, id, access from users where username = @username and password = MD5(@password)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTextBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", passwordTextBox.Text);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    //Check whether user exists
                    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        //If the user exist - allow to log in

                        //Store the infrmation from the query to UserDetails class to be used in other forms
                        UserDetails.Username = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                        UserDetails.userId = (int)dt.Rows[0][2];
                        UserDetails.accessId = (int)dt.Rows[0][3];

                        //Save the username details - for future logins
                        Properties.Settings.Default.username = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                        //Hide this form and open the main Dashboard Form
                        this.Hide();
                        var dashboard = new Dashboard();
                        dashboard.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                        dashboard.Show();
                    }

                    //If failed login - show message
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login failed", "Technical - Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserDetails.cs**

```
namespace Technical_Application.Classes
{
    public class UserDetails
    {
        private static string _username;
        private static int _userId;
        private static int _accessId;

        public static string Username
        {
            get
            {
                return _username;
            }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
            }
        }

        public static int userId
        {
            get
            {
                return _userId;
            }
            set
            {
                _userId = value;
            }
        }

        public static int accessId
        {
            get
            {
                return _accessId;
            }
            set
            {
                _accessId = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Dashboard.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Technical_Application.Classes;
using Technical_Application.Forms.Settings.Admin;
using Tulpep.NotificationWindow;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Technical_Application.Forms.SubForm.FSQM;

namespace Technical_Application.Forms
{
    public partial class Dashboard : Form
    {
        public Dashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Show welcome message
            welcomeText.Text = $"Hello {UserDetails.Username}!";

            //Depending on the users accessID load specific content only
            if (UserDetails.accessId == 1)
            {

            }
            if (UserDetails.accessId == 2)
            {
                viewRequestedDocumentsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                adminControlToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
            }
            if (UserDetails.accessId == 3)
            {
                requestDocumentAmendmentToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                viewRequestedDocumentsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                labelRoom.Visible = false;
                adminControlToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
            }
            if (UserDetails.accessId == 4)
            {
                technical.Visible = false;
                labelRoom.Visible = false;
                production.Visible = false;
                settings.Visible = false;
                welcomeText.Text = $"Hello {UserDetails.Username}! \n Your account is set as inactive.";
            }

        }


        //Check if form is already open
        private Form findForm(string text)
        {
            var found = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Text == text);

            if (!(found is null))
            {
                found.BringToFront();
                if (found.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    found.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
            }
            return found;
        }

        private void requestDocumentAmendmentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("Request Document Amendment");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var newDoc = new Request_Document_Amendment();
                newDoc.Show();
            }
        }

        private void viewRequestedDocumentsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("View Requested Documents");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var viewDoc = new ViewRequestedDocuments();
                viewDoc.Show();
            }
        }

        private void labelFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("Label Room");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var labelForm = new Technical_Application.Forms.Label_Form___Label_Room.Main();
                labelForm.Show();
            }
        }

        private void requestLabelSignOffToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("Request Label Sign Off");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var request_Label = new Request_Label_Sign_Off();
                request_Label.Show();
            }
        }

        private void labelSignOffSheetsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("Sign Off");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var labelSignOff = new LabelSignOff();
                labelSignOff.Show();
            }
        }

        private void requestLabelsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("Production");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var request_labels = new Technical_Application.Forms.Label_Form___Production.Main();
                request_labels.Show();
            }
        }

        private void adminControlToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("Admin Control");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var adminControl = new Admin_Control();
                adminControl.Show();
            }
        }

        private void changePasswordToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("Change Password - User");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var changePassword = new Technical_Application.Forms.Settings.User.changePassword();
                changePassword.Show();
            }
        }

        private void FoodSafetyQM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var found = findForm("FSQM");
            if (found is null)
            {
                var FSQM = new FSQMMain();
                FSQM.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I begin, I want to call out something really positive. It's great that you're using parameters when reading data from the database; it's very easy to fall into the trap of using plain string concatenation, and there are liable to be severe consequences in doing so.

#### Capitalize public property names in `UserDetails`

Since these are all public properties, the [general guidelines from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-properties) say they should be `UserId` and `AccessId`, not `userId` and `accessId`

#### Mark `UserDetails` as `static`

Because all the members are `static`.

#### Use [auto-implemented properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) in `UserDetails`

Since your fields are all private, and there's nothing special in either the getters or the setters, you should use auto-implemented properties. Auto-implemented properties can be used for `static` properties, and in a `static` class:

```
public static class UserDetails {
    public static string UserName {get;set;}
    public static int UserId {get;set;}
    public static int AccessId {get;set;}
}
```

#### Replace multiple `if` blocks which test on the same expression (`accessId`) with a `switch` in the `Dashboard` constructor

```
switch (userDetails.AccessId) {
    case 2:
        viewRequestedDocumentsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
        adminControlToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
        break;
    case 3:
        requestDocumentAmendmentToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
        viewRequestedDocumentsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
        labelRoom.Visible = false;
        adminControlToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
        break;
    case 4:
        technical.Visible = false;
        labelRoom.Visible = false;
        production.Visible = false;
        settings.Visible = false;
        welcomeText.Text = $"Hello {UserDetails.Username}! \n Your account is set as inactive.";
        break;
}
```

#### Refactor repetitive "find form or open new" code in `Dashboard`

You have code like the following multiple times in `Dashboard.cs`:

```
var found = findForm("Request Document Amendment");
if (found is null)
{
    var newDoc = new Request_Document_Amendment();
    newDoc.Show();
}
```

Firstly, do you expect there to be multiple windows of the same type with different values of the `Text` property? If not, I think it much more expressive to search for a form of a particular type.

Also, if you pass in type information to `findForm` and the form is not found, `findForm` can use that type information to create a new form instance of that type.

Something like this [generic method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods):

```
private TForm findOrOpenForm<TForm>() where TForm : Form, new() {
    var found = Application.OpenForms.OfType<TForm>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (!(found is null)) {
        found.BringToFront();
        if (found.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
            found.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    } else {
        found = new TForm();
        found.Owner = this;
        found.Show();
    }
    return found; // This allows further actions outside of `findOrOpenForm`; you may not need it.
}
```

which you could then call like this:

```
private void requestDocumentAmendmentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    findOrOpenForm<Request_Document_Amendment>();
```

(NB. It may be possible to simplify this even further, but I think it would require some reflection.)

#### Consider using [`Add`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection_Add_2.htm) with an explicit data type instead of [`AddWithValue`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection_AddWithValue.htm)

When you use `AddWithValue` to add parameters, you're relying on the MySQL provider to figure out the corresponding data type based the object that's been passed in. I know that -- at least in SQL Server -- there may be performance penalties if the algorithm guesses incorrectly ([link1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/#:%7E:text=To%20follow%20best%20practices%2C%20avoid,and%20worth%20a%20few%20keystrokes.), [link2](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)); I don't know if the same holds true for MySQL, but I would suggest checking this.

#### Consider using a [`DataReader`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm) instead of `DataTable` and `DataAdapter`

Per [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders):

> You can use the ADO.NET DataReader to retrieve a read-only, forward-only stream of data from a database.

Since you're only retrieving a single row of data, and you're not reusing the retrieved data in any way (outside of the single row check), I think a `MySqlDataReader` is a better choice here.

Comment: Hello again :) .. thanks once again for an answer. Regarding the `findOrOpenForm` I have an error `The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

Comment: @LV98 Fixed. I'm writing all this stuff outside the IDE, so there may be some errors.

Comment: @LV98 I've added another point, about DataReader.

Comment: Appreciate your review Zev - making all my changes now and having a read about it :)

Comment: Regarding open form.. what is the type of logic used? Is it a function or what is it?... Never seen anything like that in C#?

Comment: Hi, if I wanted to add `.Owner = this;` to all forms opened, how would I implement it?

Comment: RE _Is it a function or what is it?_ @LV98 Do you mean `=>` (AKA "fat arrow")? [Expression-bodied members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) is a syntax introduced in C# 6 and expanded in C# 7 that lets you use `=>` and a single expression instead of a full-blown method body.. And yes, it is a function in this case.

Comment: @LV98 RE `.Owner` -- Presumably `Owner` is a property on `Form`. I've updated `findOrOpenForm` to do this.